# Filter arrray using multiple conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects named fieldValues. I want to remove objects in which type does not starts with A,C,G and ends with utt,alt and mor.

```
 [   
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "B-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language4",
        "type": "D-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language6",
        "type": "F-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "B-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language4",
        "type": "D-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language6",
        "type": "F-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "B-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language4",
        "type": "D-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language6",
        "type": "F-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "B-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language4",
        "type": "D-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language6",
        "type": "F-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "B-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language4",
        "type": "D-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language6",
        "type": "F-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-mor"
    }
]
```

I tried to filter array by spliting type with '-' and find the objects which should not included and then splice from the array. But i did'nt get the expected result.

Expected Result after filter:-

```
[   
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "B-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language4",
        "type": "D-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language6",
        "type": "F-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "B-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language4",
        "type": "D-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language6",
        "type": "F-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-mor"
    }
]
```

Comment: Add JavaScript to post, refer to how to make a [mcve].

Comment: Use a regex in your filter function.
And if that does not work, please post your attempt here.

Comment: @Chetna Your expected result does not seem to match your description of what you want to do.
You want to filter out objects that start with ACG and end with utt/alt/mor, but in your example data you have "A-utt" and A-alt

Comment: @Rainer Plumer... I want to remove all objects of type utt, alt and mor which do not contain A,C, G before '-'

Comment: @Chetna In your expected output you have ""type": "E-utt" 
Why is that expected?

Comment: @Chetna Post the JavaScript you tried and an example of what you expect. I already have a working example of a NAND Gate, but I deleted it because your question does not provide the proper information to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the conditions can be considered two inputs to [a NOT and an AND Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate).

```
const inputs = [["A", "C", "G"], ["utt", "alt", "mor"]];
```

As mentioned in question the value of each type is split at '-'

```
let values = object.type.split('-'); // ex. ['A', 'def']
```

This is how the two inputs should be processed:

```
let A = inputs[0].includes(values[0]) ? 1 : 0;
let B = inputs[1].includes(values[1]) ? 1 : 0;
```

`.filter()` returns `true` values so we'll need a NOT Gate to return all values of B (`["utt", "alt", "mor"]`) that **do not match**:

```
// NOT Gate will return all objects with `type:` `"*-def"` or `"*-kat"`
!B ? 1 : 0
```

The second half of the return is filtered by a AND Gate which requires the values of A (`["A", "C", "G"]`) and B to match:

```
/* 
AND Gate will only return combinations that include both 
A (`["A", "C", "G"]`) and B (`["utt", "alt", "mor"]`) 
*/
A && B ? 1 : 0
```

Finally the returned object will be determined by two chained ternaries that act as a NOT and an AND Gate:

```
return !B ? 1 : A && B ? 1: 0
```

[image: NOT = !B ? 1 : ... AND = A && B ? 1 : ...(0)]

---

#### Demo

```js
let data = [
{language:"language1",type:"A-def"},{language:"language1",type:"B-def"},{language:"language3",type:"C-def"},{language:"language4",type:"D-def"},{language:"language5",type:"E-def"},{language:"language6",type:"F-def"},{language:"language7",type:"G-def"},{language:"language1",type:"A-utt"},{language:"language1",type:"B-utt"},{language:"language3",type:"C-utt"},{language:"language4",type:"D-utt"},{language:"language5",type:"E-utt"},{language:"language6",type:"F-utt"},{language:"language7",type:"G-utt"},{language:"language1",type:"A-kat"},{language:"language1",type:"B-kat"},{language:"language3",type:"C-kat"},{language:"language4",type:"D-kat"},{language:"language5",type:"E-kat"},{language:"language6",type:"F-kat"},{language:"language7",type:"G-kat"},{language:"language1",type:"A-alt"},{language:"language1",type:"B-alt"},{language:"language3",type:"C-alt"},{language:"language4",type:"D-alt"},{language:"language5",type:"E-alt"},{language:"language6",type:"F-alt"},{language:"language7",type:"G-alt"},{language:"language1",type:"A-mor"},{language:"language1",type:"B-mor"},{language:"language3",type:"C-mor"},{language:"language4",type:"D-mor"},{language:"language5",type:"E-mor"},{language:"language6",type:"F-mor"},{language:"language7",type:"G-mor"}
];

const prefix = ["A", "C", "G"];
const suffix = ["utt", "alt", "mor"];

const NOTxAND = (array, key, termsA, termsB) => {
  const inputs = [termsA, termsB];
  return array.filter(obj => {
    let values = obj[key].split('-');
    let first = inputs[0].includes(values[0]) ? 1 : 0;
    let last = inputs[1].includes(values[1]) ? 1 : 0;
    return !last ? 1 : first && last ? 1 : 0;
  });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(NOTxAND(data, 'type', prefix, suffix)));
```

Answer (score 0):

use

`fieldValues.filter(v=>!(!"ACG".includes(v.type[0])&&['mor','utt','alt'].includes(v.type.slice(2))));`

Answer (score 0):

```
langs = [   
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "B-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language4",
        "type": "D-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language6",
        "type": "F-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-def"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "B-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language4",
        "type": "D-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language6",
        "type": "F-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-utt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "B-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language4",
        "type": "D-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language6",
        "type": "F-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-kat"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "B-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language4",
        "type": "D-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language6",
        "type": "F-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-alt"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "A-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language1",
        "type": "B-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language3",
        "type": "C-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language4",
        "type": "D-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language5",
        "type": "E-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language6",
        "type": "F-mor"
    },
    {
        "language": "language7",
        "type": "G-mor"
    }
];

langs.filter( (l) => {
    return !l.type.match(/^[^ACG]-(utt|alt|mor)$/);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it is working fine now. Here filteredArray passed contains the array mentioned above. But i think it can be done in a better way.

```
filterEntries(filteredArray){
            var filterValues=[];
            var filterInvalidEntries=[];
            var languageCode=['A','C','G']
            var entries=['utt','alt','mor'];
            entries.forEach((entry)=>{
                filterValues=filteredArray.filter(x=>x.type.split('-')[1]==entry);
                filterInvalidEntries.push(...filterValues.filter((val) => languageCode.indexOf(val.type.split('-')[0])== -1));
            });
            filteredArray = filteredArray.filter( ( el ) => !filterInvalidEntries.includes( el ) );
        },
```